# Why is my ruby case statement not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement, case

What's wrong with that?
Yes, I could make an if else statement, but I wanna do that with case statements.

In my Controller

```
query_limit = case current_user
                when nil
                  return 5
                when is_admin?
                  return 200
                when has_role?('registered')
                  return 20
                else
                  return 5
              end


NoMethodError (undefined method `is_admin?' for #<V1::MyController:123123123>):
```

`puts query_limit` # is always ELSE when I do this:

```
 query_limit = case current_user
                    when nil
                      return 5
                    when current_user.is_admin?
                      return 200
                    when current_user.has_role?('registered')
                      return 20
                    else
                      return 5
                  end
```

Model User

```
class User
  def is_admin?
    self.has_role?('administrator')
  end

  def has_role?(the_role)
    self.roles.any? {|role| role.slug == the_role}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Ruby documentation:

> Case statements consist of an optional condition, which is in the position of an argument to case, and zero or more when clauses. The first when clause to match the condition (or to evaluate to Boolean truth, if the condition is null) “wins”, and its code stanza is executed.

If you specify `current_user` as the case condition, then the first `when` expression that matches `current_user` will be executed. `current_user.is_admin?` returns a boolean value which will never be equal to `current_user`, so your second example will always take the `else` branch:

```
case current_user
  when nil  # current_user != nil, skip condition
    return 5
  when current_user.is_admin?  # current_user != current_user.is_admin?, skip condition
    return 200
  when current_user.has_role?('registered')  # and so on
    return 20
  else
    return 5
end
```

Your first example is broken because there is no local `is_admin?` method defined. `case` does not know to call `is_admin?` on `current_user` in this case.

To fix your code, you can remove case condition. In this case the first `when` clause that evaluates to a truthy value will be chosen:

```
case  # no current_user here!
  when current_user.nil?  # current_user.nil? is false, skip condition
    return 5
  when current_user.is_admin?  # current_user.is_admin? is truthy, run this one!
    return 200
  when current_user.has_role?('registered')
    return 20
  else
    return 5
end
```

Comment: `when nil` without any argument for `case`?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. Fixed.

Comment: Now that it's fixed, you have the exact same code as my answer.

Comment: This helped me write the case...when statement for my model method. My conditions required use of `self` and I was confused about how to incorporate that with case...when. This answer helped me realized I don't need to use a statement with the case declaration. I can just use "when" like "if". Much easier go of it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The way `case` works is it doesn't call whatever method you wanted to put in the `when` clause. Instead it uses `===` on the `when` clause passing the `case`-ed thingy as argument.

In other words:

```
case user
when admin? then 42
end
```

Isn't

```
42 if user.admin?
```

But

```
42 if admin? === user
```

And as you don't have an `admin?` method in the controller, you get a `NoMethodError`.

---

Just rewrite it with simple `if` - `elsif` instead.

Answer (score 5):

ndn explained already in his answer why the case statement in your example is not working.

You can switch to an `if/elsif` block or a slightly longer `when current_user.admin?` syntax. Or you can define some methods for returning lambdas:

```
def is_admin?
  ->(user) { user.is_admin? }
end

def has_role?(role)
  ->(user) { user.has_role?(role) }
end
```

With these methods you can write:

```
query_limit = case current_user
              when nil then 5
              when is_admin? then 200
              when has_role?('registered') then 20
              else 5
              end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write it this way, which is basically a disguised `if/elsif`:

```
query_limit = case
                when current_user.nil?
                  return 5
                when current_user.is_admin?
                  return 200
                when current_user.has_role?('registered')
                  return 20
                else
                  return 5
                end
```

Answer (score 1):

A case statement works by comparing the given value against the values of the `when` statements (using `===`). So `case current_user; when current_user.is_admin?` checks whether `current_user` is equal to `current_user.is_admin?`, which it's obviously not going to be.

Basically

```
case x
  when y
    case1
  when z
    case2
  ...
end
```

is equivalent to

```
if y === x
  case1
elsif z === x
  case2
...
end
```

If that structure does not fit your use case, you should use `case`.

PS: `return` returns from the current method, so it's not what you want here.

PPS: You can also use `case` without an expression as a different way to write an arbitrary if-elsif chain. So you could do what you want like this:

```
query_limit = case
  when current_user == nil
    5
  when current_user.is_admin?
    200
  ...
end
```

But of course you can also just use a plain if-elsif for this. It's really just a matter of preference.